# Why does my Windows 10 installed in a KVM virtual machine, need an installation iso?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, iso, kvm-virtualization

I installed Windows 10 inside a KVM Virtual Machine by downloading the Win 2020 iso image from the Microsoft site. The virtual machine worked fine till I moved the Windows iso.

Why? What did I do wrong?

When I try to start the Win 10 I get the following error

```
Error starting domain: Cannot access storage file '/home/mrbuntu/Documents/Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64.iso': No such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 111, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 66, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kw
```

Comment: In your VM, do you have the ISO mounted as a CDrom?

Comment: Not sure of that.  I had downloaded the iso image from the microsoft site and saved it to my docuuments folder. I then installed Win 10 using the iso. I had used the local install media option in virt-manager while creating a new machine. The only defaults I had changed were the memory and didk size. The win10 VM was working fine, till I moved the iso image to a backup disk. Then it started to give me this error.

Comment: You could run the virtual manager, open (not start) the VM and click on details.  Check to see if theres a cdrom defined, and if so, if that cdrom is being specified to open the iso file.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I removed the source path to the iso in the Sata CdRom, and the VM booted fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 is booting from the iso Virtual Disk instead of booting from the installed Windows 10 guest OS that is listed in Virtual Machine Manager. Remove the Source path to the Windows 10 iso in the CDROM in Virtual Machine Manager as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Yes that had worked, I removed the iso path using the comments by Charles Greene below and it worked fine